# Namespace clash after including windows.h

Tags: c++, class, enums, namespaces

```
#include "windows.h"

namespace Hello {
  enum class PARITY {
    PARITY_NONE = 0U,
    PARITY_ODD = 1U,
    PARITY_EVEN = 2U,
  };
}

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

So, the above code fails with the following errors
[image]

and I think the reason is `windows.h` has definitions for symbols `PARITY_NONE` and the remaining. I'm failing to understand why there is a clash when I kept my enums in a different namespace. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: MACRO defined by WinBase.h.

Comment: windows.h defines a bunch of **macros**. Macros don't respect namespaces. So, yes, you have to dodge them. The worst culprit is `min`: the macro blows up uses of the standard library algorithm with that name.

Comment: `#undef PARITY_NONE` and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: `PARITY_NONE` is a #define https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-commprop

Comment: Btw, as you use `enum class`, you might omit prefix. (`enum class PARITY { NONE = 0U, ODD = 1U, EVEN = 2U };`)

Comment: @Jarod42, yeah I changed the names of the enum entries. It worked.